# Trying to segue from ViewController with UITableView of sponsors to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm still new to iOS programming and I am trying to implement an app that displays information for students attending a weekend long hackathon. I'm currently working on a table filled with a list of sponsors and when you click one sponsors Disclosure Button, I want it to segue to another page that simply displays the name of the sponsor and a web view containing their website.

I thought I set up my prepareForSegue method up appropriately but nothing happens when I try to make a selection in my iOS Simulator. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me if I am missing something?

[image: StoryBoard Screenshot]
[image: iOS Simulator Screenshot]

**SponsorMasterViewController .h file starts here**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SponsorDetailViewController.h"


@interface SponsorMasterViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableOfSponsers;

@end
```

**SponsorMasterViewController .m file begins here**

```
#import "SponsorMasterViewController.h"

@interface SponsorMasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation SponsorMasterViewController {

    NSArray *allSponsors;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    Sponsor *sponUber = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponUber.name = @"Über Operations LLC";
    sponUber.url = @"https://www.uberops.com";

    Sponsor *sponStar = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponStar.name = @"Starbucks";
    sponStar.url = @"http://www.starbucks.com";

    Sponsor *sponRen = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponRen.name = @"Renegade Runner";
    sponRen.url = @"https://fsudelivery.com";

    Sponsor *sponOEI = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponOEI.name = @"Office of Entrepreneurship";
    sponOEI.url = @"http://sga.fsu.edu/oei.shtml";

    Sponsor *sponJim = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponJim.name = @"The Jim Morgan Institute for Global Entrepreneurship";
    sponJim.url = @"http://business.fsu.edu/jmi";

    Sponsor *sponMail = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponMail.name = @"MailChimp";
    sponMail.url = @"http://mailchimp.com";

    Sponsor *sponGen = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponGen.name = @"Genivia";
    sponGen.url = @"http://www.genivia.com";

    Sponsor *sponFL = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponFL.name = @"FLorida IT Career";
    sponFL.url = @"https://fitc.cci.fsu.edu";

    Sponsor *sponDOMI = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponDOMI.name = @"domiventures";
    sponDOMI.url = @"http://www.domistation.com";

    Sponsor *sponCode = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponCode.name = @"Code School";
    sponCode.url = @"https://www.codeschool.com";

    Sponsor *sponIonic = [[Sponsor alloc] init];
    sponIonic.name = @"Ionic Security";
    sponIonic.url = @"https://www.ionic.com";

    allSponsors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sponUber, sponStar, sponRen, sponOEI,
                   sponJim, sponMail, sponGen, sponFL, sponDOMI, sponCode,
                   sponIonic, nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - TableView Functions

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //Determine number of sections in my table
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [allSponsors count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SponserCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Sponsor *company = [allSponsors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = company.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sponsorSegue"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        SponsorDetailViewController *sponsorDetailController = (SponsorDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


        sponsorDetailController.spon = [allSponsors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
@end
```

**SponsorDetailViewController .h file begins here**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Sponsor.h"

@interface SponsorDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *sponsorName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Sponsor *spon;

@end
```

**SponsorDetailViewController .m file begins here**

```
#import "SponsorDetailViewController.h"

@interface SponsorDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation SponsorDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Set the Sponse Label
    [self.sponsorName setText:self.spon.name];

    //Process sponsor url
    NSURL *sponsorURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.spon.url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:sponsorURL];

    //fit contents of website inside my webview
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

with something like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sponsorSegue" sender:[self.allSponsors objectAtIndexPath: indexPath]];
}
```

Then change you prepare for segue to
sponsorDetailController.spon = sender;

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have a push segue defined in the Storyboard from masterViewController to DetailViewController.

To perform the segue, you will need to implement UITableView Delegate methods, specifically `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

`PrepareForSegue` is a preparation for segues, it's not performing the segues.

However, it's not happening when you tap the disclosure detail button, but when you tap the cell if you follow this implementation.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for that clarification